# How do you change host management credentials for a cluster in System Center Virtual Machine Manager?

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, system-center

How do you change the **Host Management Credentials** in System Center Virtual Machine Manager for servers in a cluster?

If I right click on the server and go to properties I can see the **Run As account** under the **Host Access** section. But the box to select a different account is grayed out.

If I right click on the cluster and go to properties, there is no **Host Access** section.

Answer (score 1):

This change can be done from the PowerShell command window.

1. In the ribbon inside VMM click the PowerShell button
2. Run the command `$YourCluster = Get-SCVMHostCluster -Name YOUR-CLUSTER-NAME` replacing `YOUR-CLUSTER-NAME` with the name of your cluster.
3. Run the command `$YourRunAs = Get-SCRunAsAccount -Name "YOURRUNASACCOUNT"` replacing `YOURRUNASACCOUNT` with the name of the run as account inside of VMM. This could be different than the actual account name
4. Type `$YourCluster` and and hit enter to make sure that the variable contains the right cluster. Do the same for `$YourRunAs`.
5. Run `Set-SCVmHostCluster -VMHostCluster $YourCluster -VMHostManagementCredential $YourRunAs`

It can take a minute to run, but afterwards your hosts in the cluster will be managed with the new Run As account. You can right click on any host and go to properties > Host Access to verify.